# GraphQLError Execption while Fetching data ( /PublicationMapping) Unable to load DynamicContent Module

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2

Running Sites 9.0 and DXA 2.2 , we found getting following Error when we access the URL

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We reviewed the customer setup and we saw following error - Unable to get response from OData service: Bad Request. on the content service

[image]

We reviewed the configuration and we found the discovery service and token service endpoint was not https. after we changed the protocol from http to https the issue was fixed.

I would like to share so this will help others if they find similar issue.